# Tenant does not have a SPO license when updating user

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've been using Microsoft Graph API to create users in Azure Active Directory, but when I try to update skills or schools I get error:

```
 PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me 
     {
        "skills": ["skills-value"]
     }

{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Tenant does not have a SPO license.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "804948b5-f087-4be8-bdf0-ab49dccf7efc",
            "date": "2018-04-14T17:55:52"
        }
    }
}
```

Also when I try to update for example businessPhones it's work fine, I get no errors.

```
 PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me 
{
    "businessPhones": ["businessPhones-value"],
}

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft Graph is a front-end which intelligently wraps a suite of Microsoft and Office 365 APIs into a single endpoint. This includes free and paid services, and ultimately to access certain APIs you will need to have a subscription for the services which host the underlying API.

In this case, you are seeing that the `skills` attribute on the user is stored in SharePoint Online, and if you do not have a SharePoint license, you will not be able to use that property.

If you are simply looking for a way around this, you might look into storing and retrieving your skill information using [Add custom data to resources using extensions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_overview) which is stored in Azure AD and should be totally free to access.

Comment: Shawn is correct, but the link provided is not quite right (no fault of yours Shawn - the topic you linked to needs to be removed).  Please take a look at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_overview instead.